# Removing strange characters from MySQL data

Tags: mysql

Somewhere along the way, between all the imports and exports I have done, a lot of the text on a blog I run is full of weird accented A characters.

When I export the data using mysqldump and load it into a text editor with the intention of using search-and-replace to clear out the bad characters, searching just matches every "a" character.

Does anyone know any way I can successfully hunt down these characters and get rid of them, either directly in MySQL or by using mysqldump and then reimporting the content?

Comment: You'd need to use a text editor that allows for strict binary comparisons on characters. UTF-8 aware ones will consider 'a' the same as 'Â'

Comment: Any recommendations? I'd prefer an OS X application, but I do have access to a Windows 7 machine if need be.

Comment: @AndySoell
`UPDATE  tablename SET colname= CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(colname USING latin1) USING utf8)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is an encoding problem; the `Â` is a non-breaking space (HTML entity `&nbsp;`) in Unicode being displayed in Latin1.

You might try something like this... first we check to make sure the matching is working:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_field LIKE BINARY '%Â%'
```

This should return any rows in `some_table` where `some_field` has a bad character. Assuming that works properly and you find the rows you're looking for, try this:

```
UPDATE some_table SET some_field = REPLACE( some_field, BINARY 'Â', '' )
```

And that should remove those characters (based on the page you linked, you don't really want an nbsp there as you would end up with three spaces in a row between sentences etc, you should only have one).

If it doesn't work then you'll need to look at the encoding and collation being used.

EDIT: Just added `BINARY` to the strings; this should hopefully make it work regardless of encoding.

Comment: I tried the first query you suggest, but the "Â" character get stripped out when I paste it into my Terminal application. This has given me some good direction to look in, though.

Comment: Oh that will make it more of a pain... I usually use MySQL Workbench. If you can ssh in to the database server, you can use MySQL Workbench over an SSH tunnel.

Comment: Ah, I do have Sequel Pro, and that query works there. Fantastic, thanks so much for this! I had almost resigned myself to fixing hundreds of posts by hand.

Comment: Logically, replacement should be a space in the update query as we are replacing the space character. That is 'RyanÂP' to 'Ryan P'

Comment: @Thomas That was not the case with the original data (now fixed) from the OP. Removing the character was the correct operation for this data set, as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer did not work for me.

From here http://nicj.net/mysql-converting-an-incorrect-latin1-column-to-utf8/  I have found that the binary code for Â character is c2a0 (by converting the column to VARBINARY and looking what it turns to).
Then here http://www.oneminuteinfo.com/2013/11/mysql-replace-non-ascii-characters.html found the actual solution to remove (replace) it:

```
update entry set english_translation = unhex(replace(hex(english_translation),'C2A0','20')) where entry_id = 4008;
```

The query above replaces it to a space, then a normal trim can be applied or simply replace to '' instead.

Comment: This one solves my problem, mine was using "A0" or CHAR(160) then I had it replaced similarly with "20".

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem and it is annoying, but solvable. As well as Â you may find you have a whole load of characters showing up in your data like these: 
    â€œ
This is connected to encoding changes in the database, but so long as you do not have any of these characters in your database that you want to keep (e.g. if you are actually using a Euro symbol) then you can strip them out with a few MySQL commands as previously suggested.

In my case I had this problem with a Wordpress database that I had inherited, and I found a useful set of pre-formed queries that work for Wordpress here http://digwp.com/2011/07/clean-up-weird-characters-in-database/

It's also worth noting that one of the causes of the problem in the first place is opening a database in a text editor which might change the encoding in some way. So if you can possibly manipulate the database using MySQL only and not a text editor this will reduce the risk of causing further trouble.